# select all rows that count of quantity fields least equal- Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Table like `ProductInventory` , In that I have some product with quantity .

I want select all rows where The least of a field `equals` to my input(number) .

I try with this :

```
List<product> Products = new List<product> { 
    new product{Id=1,Name="A",Quantity=1},
    new product{Id=1,Name="A",Quantity=2},
    new product{Id=1,Name="A",Quantity=3},
    new product{Id=1,Name="B",Quantity=4},
    new product{Id=1,Name="B",Quantity=7}
};

var result = Products
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
    .Where(g => (int)g.Sum(r =>r.Quantity)<= 4)
    .ToList();
```

but it causes a return zero.

example:
[image]

Comment: your question not clear ? what did you trying ? if yes share code

Comment: I dont know how can I do this and I dont any trying becuase I dont have any idea

Comment: `I searched on google but cant find any result.` I highly doubt that ... try `LINQ where clause` and hit "I'm feeling Lucky"

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer My english is not very well and I dont know what should be search

Comment: seriously very confusing that what you want to do

Comment: please see https://dotnetfiddle.net/SmL3DI

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer see new update

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is it possible in linq or not. But you can try this.

```
var result = Products.AsEnumerable().Where(g => g.Name == "A").ToList();

int userInput =4;
var total = 0;
var selectList = new List<product>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
   for (int j = i; j < result.Count; j++)
    {
      if (total + result[j].Quantity <= userInput)
      {
         total += result[j].Quantity;
         selectList.Add(result[j]);
       }
     }
     if (total == userInput)
       break;
     else
     {
        total = 0;
        selectList = new List<product>();
      }
}
if(userInput!=total)
 selectList = new List<product>();
```

Comment: Please check. you are find an item with name="A" and quantity=4. but there is no item with that condition in your list.

Comment: Ok , I know , but in fiddel that retuen two recirds that sum of `quantity = 4` ,

Comment: if user input `4` this should return all rows witch sum of `quantity = 4`

Comment: ok my dear , its wrong , see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ad47pX , sorry dont try againg

Comment: there is no item that's quantity will be 6 from your sample data.

Comment: I have `12` items as `A`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111421/discussion-between-shamim-reza-and-uthman-rahimi).

Answer (score 1):

With that latest update, I think I finally understand what you are trying to do.

This won't work however, because you cant build the sum of booleans.

```
var result = Products
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Sum(r =>r.Quantity== 4))
    .ToList();
```

What you actually want is

```
var result = Products
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Sum(r =>r.Quantity) >= 4) //or == 4 or whatever
    .ToList();
```

Comment: your code is ok , thanks , and i change code in new update  , I should try with your code